# Convolution of square function with itself

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convolution

I have the square function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and I am trying to calculate the convolution $(f * f)(t)$ using the definition of convolution

$$(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)g(t - \tau)d\tau$$

What I have so far is

$$(f*f)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)f(t - \tau)d\tau$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{0} \underbrace{f(\tau)}_{\equiv 0}f(t - \tau)d\tau + \int_{0}^{1} f(\tau)f(t - \tau)d\tau + \int_{1}^{\infty} \underbrace{f(\tau)}_{\equiv 0}f(t - \tau)d\tau$$
$$= \int_{0}^{1} \underbrace{f(\tau)}_{\equiv 1}f(t - \tau)d\tau = \int_{0}^{1} f(t - \tau)d\tau$$

But now I don't understand how to go further, because the integrand is not continous. If you visualize the integral for diffent cases of $t$ one can see that the result must be
$$(f*f) (t) = \begin{cases} 0, &  t \lt 0 \\t,  & 0\leq t \le 1\\ 2- t, & 1\lt t \leq 2\\ 0 , & t \gt 2\end{cases}$$
but I don't see how to get there analytically. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a "trick" for convolving piecewise constant functions.

Define $g:= f * f$. Note that $\dot g = f * \dot f$. Hence,

$$\dot g (t) = f (t) * (\delta (t) - \delta (t-1)) = f (t) - f (t-1)$$

where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta. Integrating,

$$g (t) = r (t) - 2 r (t-1) + r (t-2) = \begin{cases} t & \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq 1\\ 2 - t & \text{if } 1 \leq t \leq 2\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where

$$r (t) = \begin{cases} t & \text{if } t \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

is the ramp function.

Answer (score 2):

If $t<0, f(t−τ) = 0$ for all $\tau$ in the interval.

If $0\le t \le 1$
$f(t) = \int_0^1 f(t−τ)dτ = \int_0^t f(t−τ)dτ + \int_t^1 f(t−τ)dτ=t$

If $1\le t \le 2$

$f(t) =$ $\int_0^1 f(t−τ)dτ = \int_0^{t-1} f(t−τ)dτ + \int_{t-1}^1 f(t−τ)dτ\\
1-(t-1) = 2-t$

If $2\le t, f(t−τ) = 0$ for all $\tau$ in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t - \tau = k$, so

$-d\tau=dk$,
$\implies-\int\limits_t^{t-1}f(k)dk=\int\limits_{t-1}^tf(k)dk$, $t$ is a variable, we have a window of time axis, of width 1, sliding through time. Let window slide from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. $t$ hits first to $t = 0$ and then $t-1$ hits $t = 1$. As the window slides the area under $f(k)$, area increases and then decreases. Since $f$ is an discontinuous function we break the integral into parts. Consider $t = x\in[0,1]$. So $\int\limits_0^{x}\underbrace{f(k)}_{\equiv 1}dk=x=t$, for $t = [0,$ $1]$. For $t >1,$ we consider $t-1$ is inside $t = [0,$ $1]$.

Let $t-1=x,$ $\int\limits_x^{1}\underbrace{f(k)}_{\equiv 1}dk=1-x=1-(t-1)=2-t$ for $t-1 = [0,1]\implies t=[1,2].$
As the window leaves the width of $[0,1]$ area under the curve is $0$.